# Gmail error after sending a couple of emails successfully

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

I am using `System.Net.Mail.SMTPclient` to send mails via gmail SMTP.
It is a simple task and works sometime without any problem.
But sometimes, after sending a couple of e-mails, I start getting errors.
It does not matter if I restart my service . I also start getting same error from development environment on my PC when I try to debug the application. I am just sending 100-200 e-mail messages so I don`t think it is an limitation or overload issue.
As sometimes it works and sometimes does not , I do not think that something is wrong with my code also it is a very simple task. I think I am missing something but I have no idea what it is.

This is the exception message:

> {"Failure sending mail."}
>
> {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed."}

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It might be a case of Google blocking access because they think that the email account you are using is sending automated spam. Can you check to see what happens if you manually log onto your account?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you find help [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/db6a2f36-9f7a-448d-89b8-968d45e13b45/systemnetmailsmtpexception-netioconnectionclosed).
On this page the people discuss about checking the network with **Wireshark** and changing your **web.config**. I hope this is going to help you.